# How To Make Unity APK Screen Symetric Fix To All Resolution in Mobile ? Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have created a game for mobile with unity. But when i make to apk and installed in mobile phone, i realize that the resoulution of each mobile phone is different. What i create just for my phone resoluton 1280 x 720. So when in other different mobile phone the screen look like over or smaller.

So how is the easiest way to fix all resolution in mobile , table etc when installing to mobile ? Maybe there is a app to do it ?

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: Was everthing resized or only user interface?

Comment: Hi @ŁukaszMotyczka sorry for reply late. Everthing Resize. Must when i open in any mobile phone the game will fix the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set anchor points

Go through this link [UI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rld_3SgrZw4)...